# Newrelic Azure website continues deployment Fails

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, continuous-deployment

We are using continues deployment from Visual stdio online to an Azure Website.

The deployment fails when we added new relic. 
*"Exception Message: The file 'NewRelic.Profiler.3640.log' is in use."*

If I Disable profiling, azure website>configure>app settings COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 0 then the deployment works.

Is there some way to get this to work? Is it possible to add a step to the deployment process that sets COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 0 and then afterward set COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the continues deployment work. If i copied the new relics folder out of the sites folder. And the change the new app config to use that one the site and deployment work. Not 100 % sure that new relic works but it seems to be doing alright

Comment: can you tell us the exact steps to do that please?

Comment: In azure mangment go to your website. Under the "configuration" tab there is a section called "app settings". In there settings called NEWRELIC_HOME and COR_PROFILER_PATH. Probably poitning to locations in website folder.

Go to "Dashboard" tab, for you website. On the right side you can find "Download the publish profiles" containing user and password. 

Once in with ftp you can copy the NewRelic stuff to the folder out side of the site. And change the app settings, mentioned above, to the new path. Then Restart the site. 

Hopefully the continus deployment will be smooth from now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of New Relic's Azure Web Sites integration:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/azure-web-sites#known_issues

I'm not sure if setting that Web Site app setting after deployment is possible or would cause the profiler to load.  With other types of deployment for the New Relic .NET agent, IIS needs to be restarted for the profiler to load into the web worker process.  The COR_ENABLE_PROFILING environment variable is just a flag that more or less gives the profiler permission to load.  So I think the site would require a restart even if you could set the variable later.

Making it possible to use continuous deployment with New Relic and Azure Websites would require some coordinated effort between New Relic and Microsoft.  You might file a feature request with both.